# an unfamiliar jQuery context selector?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I thought I understood jQuery context selectors, until I saw this:

```
return $('<li>',{
    html : option.text()
});
```

Can anyone explain how an object (in this case with a single param 'html') can be passed as the context?

Answer (score 3):

[See here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)

> **jQuery( html, props )**
>
> ---
>
> **html** : A string defining a single, standalone, HTML element (e.g.  or ).
>
> **props** : An map of attributes, events, and methods to call on the newly-created element

This code :

```
return $('<li>',{
    html : option.text()
});
```

is an equivalent to :

```
return $('<li>').html(option.text());
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the info - I can sleep in peace tonight.

Comment: I'm glad I've saved your night !

Comment: just for fun, here is an update to show that it IS inserting the li tag: http://jsfiddle.net/23G8X/1/

Answer (score 0):

It's not a selector, it's a [tag creator](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2), where the second parameter is an object containing attributes to be added to that tag.

In addition, some of those attributes are actually pseudo-attributes, so in this case supplying an `html` value is actually the same as setting the inner HTML of the new element.